# Flexslider text + image flashing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

Why is the content of `ul > li` flashing when using [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)? It doesn't flash when I force reload of the whole page (F5), but when you navigate around on the website, it starts flashing - but only the first slide.

The code is looking like this:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <div class="img-holder">
            <img src="/path/to/image.png" alt="" />

            <div class="text">
                Some
                Kind
                Of
                Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.slider').flexslider({
    directionNav: false,
    animation: "slide",
});
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I could do to stop this "flashing" on first image and text load?

The problem can't be related to image loading, as the text flashes too. The whole content inside the `li` item is flashing. So, what should I do?